# Checkbox and DataBase Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

**Checkbox in Rails**

My first form attempt with the multiple option:

```
#views/values/new.html.erb*

<% @values =["Power", "Independance", "Tradition"] %>
<%= form_for @resultvalue do |f| %>
   <% @values.each do | value | %>
       <%= f.check_box :values, { multiple: true }, value, false %>
       <%= f.label value %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit%>  
<% end %>
```

```rb
#controller/resultvalue_controller.rb

class ResultvaluesController < ApplicationController
[...]
 def resultvalue_params
     params.require(:resultvalue).permit(values:[])
 end
end
```

```rb
#models/resultvalue.rb

class Resultvalue < ApplicationRecord
    serialize :values, Array 
end
```

This is my log when I submit:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lf/sH123AoHdGyA==", "resultvalue"=>{"values"=>["Power", "Tradition"]}, "commit"=>"create", "id"=>"1"}
```

I have follow this tuto ->
https://medium.com/programming-problem-solving-logbook/rails-multiple-checkboxes-e9c4c7fda356

Comment: try to permit the array of values instead : `params.require(:resultvalue).permit(values: [])`

Comment: @Sovalina  Thanks, it was my mistake, so I corrected my post

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your problem is here. Can you clarify what's wrong?

Comment: I corrected my mistake. I wrote this :  ````def resultvalue_params
     params.require(:resultvalue).permit(:values)
 end```` but the correct syntax is   ````def resultvalue_params
     params.require(:resultvalue).permit(values:[])
 end````